# Post message from ASP.NET app to Twitter

Tags: twitter

I am using very simple code to post message in twitter. The code is as given below:

```
public void UpdateStatus(string username, string password, string tweetMsg)
{
     byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("status=" + tweetMsg);

      try
      {
         HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://twitter.com/statuses/update.xml");
         request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
         request.Method = "POST";
         request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
         request.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;

         string statusUpdate = string.Empty;

         using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
         {
              statusUpdate = "status=" + System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(tweetMsg);
              sw.Write(statusUpdate);
         }

         using (HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse())
         {
             // Handle response here
              using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream()))
              {
                        Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadToEnd());
              }
         }
       }
       catch (WebException ex)
       {
                Console.WriteLine("Web Error: {0}", ex.Message);
                if (ex.Response != null)
                {
                    HttpWebResponse r = (HttpWebResponse)ex.Response; 
                    using (StreamReader esr = new StreamReader(r.GetResponseStream()))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", esr.ReadToEnd());
                    } 
                }
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
                 Console.WriteLine("I/O Error: {0}", ex.Message);
        }
}
```

I am not sure why this code is not working. I am getting the exception 
    The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
But, whichever site I am referring, everywhere I find that people are able to post their messages using the same code.

Can anybody please tell me what I am missing in this code? The site that I referred for this code is http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/120468-twitter-api-posting-status/

Thanks in advance....

Hari

Answer (score 0):

The Twitter API no longer supports Basic Auth for authentication. You need to switch to OAuth which uses tokens instead of passwords.

[Twitter's guide to transitioning from Basic Auth to OAuth](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/basic_to_oauth)

[OAuth homepage](http://oauth.net/)